# Can we configure Certificate-based Authentication to connect(logon) sql client?

Tags: sql-server, security, ssl

Can we configure Certificate-based Authentication to connect(logon) sql client? or any other method to connect sql client using mutual authentication(sql server and sql client)?

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Answer originally provided in a comment by [Kin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/8783/kin):</sub>

The answer is **no**.

Only Database Mirroring and Service Broker connections can authenticate using certificates.

You might want to check Remus Rusanu 's [answer on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998377/authenticating-sql-connection-using-certificates-in-net) and his article:

[How does Certificate based Authentication work?](http://rusanu.com/2008/10/23/how-does-certificate-based-authentication-work/).

Comment: Is this still the case today? A few years ago I create a client/server system with MySQL and it was possible to configure user-accounts to require x509 client certificate which the client must have to being able to login. You could create multiple client certificates. I liked the setup, Wonder if you can do the same with MS-SQL today? (july 2019)